Как в Qt Creator 6.7.1 вывести текст в документ формата .docx (или .doc)?
Делаю проект - поисковик файлов. Проблем никаких нет, все легко, да и сама работа простецкая, за исключением одного момента - требуется вывести данные в Вордовский документ, привожу свой код ниже:
//Формирование отчета в файле
QFile dataBase("dataBase.txt");
if(!dataBase.open(QIODevice::Append))
{
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "Ошибка!", "Ошибка при открытии файла!");
}
else
{
    dataBase.write(ui -> textResult -> toPlainText().toUtf8());
    dataBase.write("\n\n");
}
dataBase.close();

Не судите строго, в Qt Creator я новичок, в документации на счет этого момента ничего не нашел.
